# Tababar application in iphone

Tags: iphone

i am making an tabbar application in which i have 4 tabbars. tabbars are working perfectly, my problem is that the title is overlapping over other tab bar. Title are a bit long like Instructional Videos. how can i fix it.

Comment: Please add code and screenshots. It is really unclear what you mean by 4 tab-bars, since most apps have 1 tab-bars and 4 tab-bar-items. Also, is your tab-bar not at the bottom of the screen and your title not at the top?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's just how it's done -- you may notice that it reduces the font size to try to fit, but it can only do so much.

Here's an alternative: Build the title text into the image to be displayed.

UIImage *textImage = ;
  int imageTag = 1; // or whatever you want
  [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"" image: textImage tag: imageTag];

If you can match the fonts, you can go ahead and put part of your title in the image and part of it in the title, as in:

UIImage *textImage = ;
  int imageTag = 1; // or whatever you want
  [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Videos" image: textImage tag: imageTag];

It will probably look a bit odd, and Apple might reject your app for it, but it's all I can think of.  Unless you are willing to accept the advice "Use a shorter title"?

Answer (score -1):

Use a shorter title.

Comment: different languages may not provide the OP the ability to shorten the word.  "Geschwindigkeitsbegrenzung" is speed limit in german, and if the OP is looking to explain a difficult concept to it's users then shortening the title is not an answer.

Comment: You have to work within your constraints. You can either use a shorter title, or you can use a different UI paradigm altogether. If you're set on a tab bar, use a shorter title. This is where you get to be creative and think of a way to express what you want to in a shorter fashion. You can abbreviate. You can use an acronym. You can use a different word or words to express the same or similar concept. Engineering is about working within constraints.